# T-SQL Execute from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build an SQL inside a stored procedure and execute it using

```
EXEC  sp_executesql
```

Now I defined a local table and tried to pass it in need to pass it in

```
CREATE TYPE mytabletypeAS TABLE (
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    Amount MONEY,
    AccountId INT
);
```

The following happens in my stored procedure, what I am trying to do is to return the output produced by `EXEC sp_executesql`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE attributevalues.sp_EvalClearingNetSpend  
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutPutTable AS mytabletype;
    DECLARE @Sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Sql  = 'INSERT INTO @OutPutTable SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Amount, AccountId FROM table1';

    EXEC  sp_executesql @Sql, N'@OutPutTable mytabletype OUTPUT', @OutPutTable OUTPUT;

    SELECT * FROM @OutPutTable 
END
```

The above is saying I cannot pass in `OUTPUT` with `@OutPutTable`

Help!!!

Comment: Table Type parameters can only be `READONLY`. Assigning it `OUTPUT` implies you want to write to it; which you can't do. Why do you want to pass a table type parameter to `sys.sp_executesql` here anyway, when you don't reference it?

Comment: Also, the `sp_` prefixed is reserved by Microsoft and should **not** be used to user objects. Doing so comes at a performance cost and can result in your procedure no longer working in the future.

Comment: Why not just use a `select` in the procedure?

Comment: sorry deleted some code accidentally

Comment: But all you do there s `INSERT INTO` it, @Emil . YOu could just `SELECT` in the dynamic statement and then you'd have no need for the table type parameter.

Comment: the above query is simplified, the original SQL is very complicated and heavily parameterised.

Comment: Then show us something that is relevant. The above has no need to be "dynamic"; there's nothing dynamic about it. The entire proc could be simplified to just `SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Amount, AccountId FROM table1;`.

Comment: I need to construct it and cannot be execute it without EXEC

Comment: all i need to know is, is there a way I can get the values from a statement executed via EXEC and return it from my SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all i need to know is, is there a way I can get the values from a statement executed via EXEC and return it from my SP

Yes.  But you can't do it with a table variable.  You can pass a table variable into the nested batch with sp_executesql just like you pass one to a stored procedure, but it has to be marked readonly, and so you can't modify it.

You can see and modify existing temporary tables in nested batches, eg

```
drop table if exists table1 
go
create table table1
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    Amount MONEY,
    AccountId INT
)

insert into table1 values (getdate(),getdate(),1,1)

go
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE EvalClearingNetSpend  
AS 
BEGIN
    create table #t( 
      StartDate DATETIME,
      EndDate DATETIME,
      Amount MONEY,
      AccountId INT)
    Declare @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Sql  = 'INSERT INTO #T SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Amount, AccountId FROM table1';
    EXEC  sp_executesql @Sql
    SELECT * FROM #T 
END
go

exec EvalClearingNetSpend
```

outputs

```
StartDate               EndDate                 Amount                AccountId
----------------------- ----------------------- --------------------- -----------
2021-03-30 08:48:32.350 2021-03-30 08:48:32.350 1.00                  1
```

Comment: EXEC  sp_executesql @Sql doesn't pass the values ... and SELECT * FROM #T  comes back empty

Comment: See updated answer with full working example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). There is no need for the level of complexity you have put in the procedure. The table `TYPE`, the call to `sys.sp_executesql`, none of it is needed. Just put the `SELECT` statement of your "dynamic" query (it's not dynamic, as there's no object injection) in your Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE attributevalues.EvalClearingNetSpend AS --Removed sp_ prefix
BEGIN
    SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Amount, AccountId FROM table1;
END;
GO
```

This completely avoids the error, that you are trying to use a table `TYPE` as an `OUTPUT` parameter, because you can't, but you don't need one here.

Comment: I think I did, @Emil . Notice the engagement you got from me in the comments about said question... The problem, as I mentioned, is that you are trying to use a table `TYPE` as an `OUTPUT`, which isn't allow, but you have no need for it at all. Remove all that, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would go through the trouble of creating a Table Type parameter and populating it inside your from and then selecting from it. But lets say you do have to do this for some reason.

You can achieve this by doing this, no need to use output parameters at all, output parameter is used to return a scalar value, here you are getting a table back and then selecting from it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_EvalClearingNetSpend  
AS 
BEGIN

Declare @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql  = N'  DECLARE @OutPutTable AS mytabletype;

                INSERT INTO @OutPutTable 
                SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Amount, AccountId 
                FROM table1;

                SELECT * FROM @OutPutTable 
                ';
EXEC  sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: Noe this doesn't produce an output

Comment: @Emil well the code in answer definitely does produce an output, can you share the changes you have made? There is something in those changes that has stopped it from returning data.